# Fitting Binomial distribution with car package

Tags: r, r-car, probability-distribution

For fitting several probability distribution for my data set, I try several distributions using `car` and `MASS` packages, for example for Poisson distribution:

```
require(car); require (MASS)

#Data set
X1 <- rnorm(100, 175, 7)
Y1 <- rbinom(100,1, 0.35)
##Fitting Poisson:
poisson <- fitdistr(Y1, "Poisson")
qqp(Y1, "pois", poisson$estimate)
```

But, If my option is Binomial distribution, `MASS` package don't support this kind of distribution, then I use `fitdistrplus` package:

```
require(fitdistrplus)
fitBinom=fitdist(data=Y1, dist="binom", fix.arg=list(size=100), start=list(prob=0.35))
```

When I try:

```
qqp(Y1, "Binomial", fitBinom$estimate)
```

Doesn't work the `qqp` function of `car` package. There are other options for fitting Binomial distribution like `qqp` function?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

qqp actually works with fitdistrplus. You only need to add all parameters for Binomial distribution. You also need to replace "Binomial" with "binom"

```
fitBinom <- fitdist(data=Y1, dist="binom", fix.arg=list(size=100), start=list(prob=0.35))
qqp(Y1, "binom", size=100, fitBinom$estimate)
```